# Cmd pop up while running rubyw or an exe built with ocra

Tags: ruby, windows-10, tk-toolkit, ocra

After this: 
[ruby executable won't start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50180523/ruby-executable-wont-start-on-win10-and-win7/50185887#50185887),

Now i have another issue with the following simple script:

```
require 'tk'
require 'tkextlib/tile'

root = TkRoot.new() 

button = Tk::Tile::TButton.new(root) {text "Hello World"}.grid
button.command {system("ipconfig > info.txt")}

Tk.mainloop()
```

If i click the Hello World button, so the Windows cmd console will pop up for less then one second. No outputs on it, i also tried to redirect its output to a file and its empty.

If i run my scprit like this:

`G:\WinRuby\efdsk>ruby efdsk.rb`

There are no problems.

So this issue will appear when i run my exe built with ocra, and also when i run my script like this:

```
rubyw efdsk.rb
```

If i comment the following line,

```
button.command {system("ipconfig > info.txt")}
```

The issue will disappear, so i think it's something related to system().
I also tried to replace the previous line with this:

```
cmd="ipconfig > info.txt"
Open3.popen3(cmd) {|stdin, stdout, stderr, wait_thr|}
```

But the cmd will appear the same when i click the button.

This is my ruby version:

```
ruby 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21 revision 56859) [x64-mingw32]
```

And this issue will appear on the following ruby versions too, tested by me:

```
ruby 2.1.5p273 (2014-11-13 revision 48405) [x64-mingw32]
ruby 2.0.0p648 (2015-12-16) [x64-mingw32]
ruby 1.9.3p551 (2014-11-13) [i386-mingw32]
```

I tried to run the exe and to compile it on other pcs too, Windows 7 and 10. Still the same issue.

Comment: Can you try to rename your script to `efdsk.rbw` and "compile" it again with ocra?

Comment: @knut I did this right now, still the same issue. I click the button and the cmd appears for less then a second, but i can see that there is no output on it

Comment: OK, then it seems to be something else. Can you open a cmd-shell (Command cmd) and start the exe from the command shell? Then you could see a message, even if the script close immediate after the start.

Comment: @knut i tried this too. But the console is still empty. I also tried to do 'start efdsk.exe > log.txt' but then the file is empty.  

If i remove from my script the 'system()' or 'popup3' methods, so this issue will be solved. But i really need them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved by myself.

First, i required this in my script:

```
require 'win32ole'
```

Then i made a batch file, containing the command i need to be printed on a file, in this case `ip config > info.txt`, and i named it `run.bat`.

After this, I replaced `system()` with the following:

```
WIN32OLE.new('Shell.Application').ShellExecute('run.bat','','','open',0)
```

This will work too:

```
WIN32OLE.new('WScript.Shell').Run("run.bat",0,0)
```

Here the documentation for [win32ole](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.3/libdoc/win32ole/rdoc/index.html)

As first parameter i used the batch file i just created, and the last parameter, the 0, made the trick. It sets the new cmd window to be hided and so it wont ever pop up again.

I tried with `rubyw efdsk.rb` and also to build an exe with ocra. No annoying windows popping up.