# Unable to create stand-alone program using Ruby/Tk with ocra

Tags: ruby, tk-toolkit, ocra

I'm having problems creating a stand-alone program with ocra using Ruby/Tk.
First of all, here's a simple test program:

```
require 'tk'

hello = TkRoot.new do
  title "Test" minsize(100, 40)
end

TkLabel.new(hello) do
  text "Tk version is #{Tk::TK_PATCHLEVEL}"
  pack { padx 15; pady 15; side 'left'}
end

Tk.mainloop
```

This will work fine if run by itself.

If I run `ocra tk-test.rb`, the application pops up as expected, but when it is terminated, an unhandled exception occurs:

```
$ ocra tk-test.rb
C:/Ruby25/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/tk-0.2.0/lib/tk/font.rb:126:in `<class:TkFont>': unhandled exception
        from C:/Ruby25/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/tk-0.2.0/lib/tk/font.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby25/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby25/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby25/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/tk-0.2.0/lib/tk/fontchooser.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby25/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby25/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby25/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/ocra-1.3.10/bin/ocra:478:in `const_get'
        from C:/Ruby25/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/ocra-1.3.10/bin/ocra:478:in `block (3 levels) in attempt_load_autoload'
        from C:/Ruby25/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/ocra-1.3.10/bin/ocra:472:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby25/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/ocra-1.3.10/bin/ocra:472:in `block (2 levels) in attempt_load_autoload'
        from C:/Ruby25/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/ocra-1.3.10/bin/ocra:470:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby25/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/ocra-1.3.10/bin/ocra:470:in `block in attempt_load_autoload'
        from C:/Ruby25/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/ocra-1.3.10/bin/ocra:464:in `loop'
        from C:/Ruby25/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/ocra-1.3.10/bin/ocra:464:in `attempt_load_autoload'
        from C:/Ruby25/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/ocra-1.3.10/bin/ocra:723:in `build_exe'
        from C:/Ruby25/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/ocra-1.3.10/bin/ocra:1203:in `block in <top (required)>'
=== Loading script to check dependencies
=== Attempting to trigger autoload of #<Class:#<Tk::Label:0x02ef01b8>>::CheckButton
=== Attempting to trigger autoload of #<Class:#<Tk::Label:0x02ef01b8>>::Entry
=== Attempting to trigger autoload of #<Class:#<Tk::Label:0x02ef01b8>>::Frame
=== Attempting to trigger autoload of #<Class:#<Tk::Label:0x02ef01b8>>::LabelFrame
=== Attempting to trigger autoload of #<Class:#<Tk::Label:0x02ef01b8>>::Listbox
=== Attempting to trigger autoload of #<Class:#<Tk::Label:0x02ef01b8>>::Menu
=== Attempting to trigger autoload of #<Class:#<Tk::Label:0x02ef01b8>>::Message
=== Attempting to trigger autoload of #<Class:#<Tk::Label:0x02ef01b8>>::PanedWindow
=== Attempting to trigger autoload of #<Class:#<Tk::Label:0x02ef01b8>>::Scale
=== Attempting to trigger autoload of #<Class:#<Tk::Label:0x02ef01b8>>::Scrollbar
=== Attempting to trigger autoload of #<Class:#<Tk::Label:0x02ef01b8>>::Spinbox
=== Attempting to trigger autoload of #<Class:#<Tk::Label:0x02ef01b8>>::Text
=== Attempting to trigger autoload of #<Class:#<Tk::Label:0x02ef01b8>>::Toplevel
=== Attempting to trigger autoload of #<Class:#<Tk::Label:0x02ef01b8>>::Clock
=== Attempting to trigger autoload of #<Class:#<Tk::Label:0x02ef01b8>>::OptionObj
=== Attempting to trigger autoload of #<Class:#<Tk::Label:0x02ef01b8>>::Fontchooser
```

Ruby was installed using Rubyinstaller with the MSYS2 development environment.

Ruby version is:

```
RUBY VERSION: 2.5.3 (2018-10-18 patchlevel 105) [i386-mingw32]
```

The installed gem versions are:

```
ocra (1.3.10)
tk (0.2.0)
```

Googling indicates others have had similar problems, but the answers all seem to be out of date or non-applicable.
For example, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50180523/ruby-executable-wont-start-on-win10-and-win7)
looks promising, but there is no such directory as `C:\Ruby25\lib\tcltk\` in my environment, so it doesn't apply.